# Unable to connect Power BI with Mysql Database

Tags: mysql, powerbi

***I am trying to make a connection of PowerBI with Mysql database. I am not able to find the server name required for connection.***

***I was able to make a connection with Postgres database. I am not able to find the server name required for connecting to Mysql Database and it just says validating credentials and asks me to install some dependencies which I have already installed multiple times.***

***Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.***

Answer (score 0):

Hey there Dan Christian, to connect Power BI Desktop with
MysqlDatabase Server please follow the below steps, we have faced a
similar issue and when we followed

```
these steps it worked:


        1.Press "Windows" key and search for "Services", in the "Services" search for "MYSQL80"(or any version that you maybe working on) and
            make sure it is running otherwise right click it and "Start" the
            service. [Click here][1]
        2.Now , Open Mysql workbench on the authorization screen you can see the ip address where Mysql is running on.[click here][2]
    
        3.In my case it's "localhost:3306" "3306" is default port for Mysql.[Click here][1]
    
        4.it is configurable we can change the host and port its running on by changing them in the Mysql settings which is the small "Tool" icon.
    
        5.After the steps 1 to 4 are done proceed with PowerBI. 
    
        6.After opening PowerBI Desktop, Goto Home.
    
        7.Click the "Get Data" Button.[click here][1]
   
    
        8.Then click "More".
    
        9.A window pops up in which there are multiple options to select on the left.
    
        10.Select "Database".[click here][1]
    
        11.Search for "Mysql Database".
    
        12.A small window with the fields "Server" and "Database" is shown.
    
        13.In the "Server" field fill "localhost:3306" if you haven't configured it to something else in the steps 1 to 5. [click here][1]
    
        14.For the sake of connection use the default database provided by Mysql "sakila".
    
        15.After this a window pops  with the options Database and Windows, select "Database" and fill in your credentials default username is "root" and enter your password.[click here][1]
    
        16.Then click "connect"  if the credentials are right a window with all the tables in sakila database.
    
        17.Now you have succesfully connected to Mysql Database in PowerBI repeat the steps to use desired databases.

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c41lh.png   [2]:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BR3yH.png
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).